# Booting an encrypted system from a flash drive without user interaction

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive, encryption, arch-linux

I have an unused desktop that I'm planning on turning to a household server running (hopefully) Arch Linux. I know that I can fully encrypt the system and have to enter a password upon each boot but I am curious if there is a possible/common method which would allow the system to be decrypted automatically at boot by using a key stored on a flash drive that plugs into the server. In this instance, the system would require the presence of the key file on the flash drive in order to boot up. Is there a simple solution to this or am I better off writing a bunch of scripts to be executed after boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional browsing of the world wide web, I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949870) guide and [this](http://blog.philippbeck.net/linux/archlinux-install-encryption-lvm-luks-grub2-69]) guide extremely helpful and was able to achieve what I originally came in search of.