# Booting a LUKS-encrypted drive with a flash drive, falling back to keyboard

Tags: linux, boot, disk-encryption, luks

I have some systems configured using GRUB as my bootloader, with an unencrypted boot partition and everything else using LVM-on-LUKS. Right now, the only way to unlock the system is for me to physically go to the keyboard and enter the password. I would like to make it possible to store a key file on a USB drive and have the system boot automatically if the USB drive is present.

[This blog post](https://tqdev.com/2022-luks-with-usb-unlock) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20240125060159/https://tqdev.com/2022-luks-with-usb-unlock)), [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713918/how-to-load-luks-passphrase-from-usb-falling-back-to-keyboard) and [this forum post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949870) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20240320123451/https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=949870)) each explain ways to do this, but in each case there is a step that basically says "edit your `/etc/crypttab` configuration", but when I open `/etc/crypttab`, the comment at the top says:

```
# NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
        beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf)
```

And indeed my system does *not* have an entry for root here. Instead, that is set up in the grub configuration, which has the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... root=/dev/mapper/vg-root cryptdevice=UUID={uuid}:cryptlvm"
```

Is the notice in `/etc/crypttab` incorrect? Or is it possible that the people who seem to think that these methods that involve editing `/etc/crypttab` have a different boot configuration? If the notice is correct, what is the correct way to get GRUB to look for a keyfile in a USB drive?

Note: [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/583900/booting-an-encrypted-system-from-a-flash-drive-without-user-interaction) also resolves in favor of the `/etc/crypttab` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the `/etc/crypttab` stuff actually would work, but I did manage to get this working using just the `grub` configuration. It turns out that this was actually quite well documented [on the ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption#Configuring_LUKS_to_make_use_of_the_keyfile) (as is usually the case). In my case, I had an `ext4`-formatted USB drive, so I went into `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and added `ext4` to `MODULES`:

```
MODULES=(ext4)
```

Then in `/etc/default/grub`, I changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to add the `cryptkey` parameter, like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet ... cryptkey=LABEL=my_usb_label:ext4:/path/to/keyfile
```

Where `/path/to/keyfile` is the path to the keyfile on the USB drive, with `/` as the root *of the USB drive*. You can find more information about using the `encrypt` hook [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#Using_encrypt_hook).